# Fastest way to iterate over a Binary Search Tree (BST) stored as unordered array?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search-tree

I have a BST which is stored as an array.

For example, the tree may look as follows

```
        4
     /    \
    2      6
   / \   /  \
  1   3  5  7
```

As an array, this tree would be stored as [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, null, etc.]

I need to implement a method to find the index of a value in **O(log(n))** time. Problem is, this array is unsorted which means that I cannot implement binary search.

What would a solution look like?

I have iterated over all elements already and found a way to find the index, but it is O(n) which isn't what is required.

```
public class Item<A extends Comparable<? super A>>
{
protected A[] items;

public Item
    {
      //Code to construct array of size 10. 
    }

public int index(A value)
{
for (int i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
 //Method to iterate through array element by element. Time complexity of O(n).
}
}

}
```

That is sample code.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess your example is not even a BST?

Comment: Your example is not a valid BST. F.eg. element with value 4 can't be in the left subtree of root (value 3)

Comment: My bad, I've fixed it.

Comment: If you have a balanced BST you should be able to search it in `O(log(n))` see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Searching

Comment: The same goes for 6 to the left of 5 ;P

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the element left and right link of an element at index `i` would be `2*i+1` and `2*(i+1)`. You can use the same algorithm as for a regular BST:

```
public int index(A value)
{
    for (int i=0; i < items.length; ) {
        if (items[i] == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        int r = value.compareTo(items[i]);
        if (r < 0) {
            i = 2*i+1;
        } else if (r > 0) {
            i = 2*(i+1);
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a quick question, does this iterate multiple times if it does not find it the first time? It seems to only iterate once.

Comment: @whowho1 yes: it's in O(log(N)). It never visits the same position twice if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

In this implementation if a parent is on index `i`, its children are on `2*i + 1` (left) and `2*i + 2` (right) indexes. If it's a BST, then you always have lower values on the left, and higher on the right. That way, you can implement an algorithm which looks first at the root, if an element is lower, look in the left sub-tree, otherwise look in the right subtree. So for example:

```
       6
     /   \
    2     8
   / \   /  \
  1   3 7    9
```

the array representation would look like this:

```
[ 6, 2, 8, 1, 3, 7, 9 ]
```

and searching algorithm would look like this

```
int findIndex(int value, int[] bst) {
    int currentRootIndex = 0;
    while (currentRootIndex < bst.length) {
        if (value == bst[currentRootIndex]) return currentRootIndex;

        if (value < bst[currentRootIndex]) currentRootIndex = 2 * currentRootIndex + 1;
        else currentRootIndex = 2 * currentRootIndex + 2;
    }

    return currentRootIndex > bst.length ? -1 : currentRootIndex;
}
```

This method returns an index of searched value if the value is found. `-1` otherwise.

Live demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/NeatQuickwittedKeyboardmacro)

Comment: and if the `value` is not present in the BST ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quick note, the array type and value type are different. My array is of type Object and value is of type A, so the comparison symbol '<' doesn't work. Also, I am not allowed to edit the parameters in the method, so the array isn't to be there.

Comment: It all depends on your implementation. I've shown an example of how it could be implemented. You need to adjust the example to your needs. I guess you need some kind of comparison function that returns (-1, 0, 1) depending on items equality and then you will be able to replace `<` with this comparison function. Also, the `bst` array argument can be removed and replaced with `this.items` (if that's your case). In short, it's not an easy copy-paste solution. You need to put a little effort to adjust it to your needs ;)